# Video signal RSSI values to determine position of a drone (Kalman? Moving mean?, etc)

Tags: regression, mean, model, moving-average

I have RSSI (strength of the signal) values of a moving drone over a fixed receiver. I want to determine when the drone is passing on top of the receiver.

[image: rssi values]

Will a moving mean be enough? The full data is here: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AqORX6Fjni7Dw5l1MFag9aacUTGOXw?e=JFyARW